# Adding a new child movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, for-loop, actionscript, movieclip

I am trying to get a cube movieclip to create another instance of itself and then add it to the stage at the coordinates right next to the previous one.  However I can't get it to keep adding more children/ can't figure out how to access the childs coords.  I attempted to add a new movieclip:mc every iteration of the for loop with the vertical and horizontal counting back by 50 every time and then,on a different thought process, i tried adding a new child every loop but I don't know how to access that childs properties.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
var countV:int=600;
var countH:int=600;
stage.addChild(havenAlpha);
var moveHOrV:Boolean=true;
var mc:MovieClip = new haven_Expand();
for(var i:int=0; i<=5; i++){

            if(moveHOrV == false){
                stage.addChild(mc);
                countH=countH-50;
                mc.x= countH;
                moveHOrV=true;

            }else if(moveHOrV == true){
                stage.addChild(mc);
                countV=countV-50;
                mc.y=countV;
                moveHOrV=false;
            }

            trace(countV,countH,moveHOrV,i);

            stage.addChild(new haven_Expand())
            stage.addChildAt(new haven_Expand(),countH);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In most Object oriented languages, variables are just pointers to the actual objects. So changing what is stored in a variable, doesn't actually make what was stored there previously go away.

To that end, you can just make one `var` to store each new object created every iteration.  Like so:

```
stage.addChild(havenAlpha);

//this var will store the clip from the preivous iteration, but we'll start it off with the first item
var prevClip:MovieClip = new haven_Expand();
prevClip.x = 600;
prevClip.y = 600;
stage.addChild(prevClip);

var curClip:MovieClip; //used in the loop below to hold the current iterations item

for(var i:int=0; i<=5; i++){
    curClip = new haven_Expand();//create new clip
    stage.addChild(curClip); //add it to the stage
    if(i % 2){ // % (modulous) gives you the remainder of the division, so this effectively will be false (0) every other time
        curClip.x = prevClip.x - curClip.width; //place this new clip just to the left of the last iteration's clip
        curClip.y = prevClip.y;
    }else if(moveHOrV == true){
        curClip.y = prevClip.y - curClip.height; //place this new clip just on top of the last iteration's clip
        curClip.x = prevClip.x;
    }

    prevClip = curClip;
}
```

I'm not sure though if the x/y math is what you desire. This will make them distribute in a diagonal fashion.   Are you actually wanting horizontal rows? I can update to show you that if desired.

Comment: Yes I will work on the algorithm to make them spread over the screen.  Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: I'm looking to get it to fill the screen from the right bottom corner.  Sort of like a flood fill. So if it was a 3x3 box it would fill like this
---    ---    ---
---    ---    --x
--x    -xx  -xx  and so on.

Comment: I don't follow,  you just want the loop to keep going until the screen is completely covered in `haven_Expand` clips?   Can you make a picture and edit your question with the picture?

Comment: So what I am doing is making a haven_expand and a nonhaven_expand on opposite corners of the screen.  When they both try to take a square they do a math.random and whoever is higher gets the square.  It is a like a competition.  Eventually I want toi have it randomly expand from each side and then they will do math.random whenever they try to take a neutral square or a enemy square.  Maybe the current haven_exapnd squares should be the background and then two others expand using the haven_expand squares as a grid guideline.

I got the haven_Expand clips to take up the entire screen.

Comment: I did it by changing the If statement so that if the prevClip.x>=100 (same code as you had) then Else if(prevClip.x<100){curClip.y = prevClip.y-50; curClip.x=600;}  This just makes the curent clip move up 50 and back to the far right for the next row.